# What's the method of collation in the language of set theory?

Tags: logic

I have read about the language of set theory and the thing I noticed is that although the alphabet and rules of formation are usually described, I have yet to see a description of the method of collation in this language. How does it look like?

Comment: There is no need to specify a collation. The language is a set of WFFs, not necessarily an ordered set of WFFs.

Comment: If it has no collation system, how can we call it a language?

Answer (score 1):

In mathematics, a [**(formal) language**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language) is nothing but a set of strings of symbols. No order (what would be called "collation" in disciplines - such as bibliography - that need to impose a linear order on their pieces of information) among the words (i.e., the strings of symbols) or even within the alphabet (i.e., the set of "symbols" used in the strings) is implied. For what it's worth, the alphabet might be the power set of $\Bbb C$, and I personally don't want to be given the task to explicitly describe a linear order on that set.

Nevertheless, for any language we have a natural *partial* order, namely by the *length* (number of symbols a string has). For example, sometimes properties of a language can be proved by induction on word length.